# Clearing Multiselect in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, multi-select

```
$("#selUser").bind('change keyup', function() {
    $('#selSubjects2').empty();


    if($(this).val().length > 0)
      $.each( $(this).val().split(','), function(i, val) {
        var option = new Option(val, val);
        option.selected = true;
        console.log("option",option);
        $('#selSubjects2').append(option);
      });

    $('#selSubjects2').trigger("change");
  });
```

[image]

I am trying to remove the options from selsubjects2 using the empty method.
When selecting a new user from the `SelUser` dropdown, I want to clear all the options in `selSubjects2` using the `empty` method.

Currently, after selecting permissions for User1, if I choose permissions for User2, it appends these new permissions to the existing options of User1. The goal is to entirely remove User1's permissions and then populate `selSubjects2` with User2's permissions. This ensures that only the permissions of the currently selected user are displayed, removing the previous user's permissions entirely.
[image]

How do I get rid of user1's permissions completely and then append the user'2 permissions?

Comment: `$(this).val()` will be an array in a multi-select, not a comma-separated string.

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551); instead, create an [mcve] in the body of your question.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, you will need to use the `.empty()` method on the correct element. Rather than referencing `$(this)`, which refers to the current element (likely selUser), you should reference `$('#selSubjects2')` since that is the element you want to clear. Additionally, you should wrap your code inside a change event handler so that it only runs when the value of selUser changes. Below is an example of how this could be implemented:

```
$("#selUser").on('change', function() {
    $('#selSubjects2').remove();

    var newSelect = $('<select></select>',{
        id: 'selSubjects2'
    });
    $('#selSubjects2').parent().append(newSelect);

    var selectedUser = $(this).val();

    if(selectedUser){
        var permissions = selectedUser.split(',');

        $.each( permissions, function(i, permission) {
            var option = new Option(permission, permission);
            option.selected = true;
            newSelect.append(option);
        });

        newSelect.trigger("change");
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello,
Thankyou for answering. The .empty() method is still not removing the <a> tags. It is appending to the existing <a> tags, only the <option> tags are changing.

Comment: you may need to use the .remove() method instead of .empty() to remove the <a> tags completely. modified the code

Comment: I tried that too. It doesn't append anything at all.  The remove method makes it even worse.